# Tabbar not displayed in certain UIViewController in navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make a navigation based application having three `UIViewController` in navigation stack. I have a bottom bar (`UITabBar`).

I want to hide tabbar when first `UIViewController` is pushed into the stack and I want to show tabbar when second `UIVIewController` is pushed.

Here is the code I have written to do so.

For First `UIVIewController`:

```
NotificationDetailsVC *obj = [[NotificationDetailsVC alloc] init];
obj.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```

For Second `UIViewController` I have done:

```
NotificationBO *obj=[self.notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
object.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:object animated:YES];
[object release];
```

Now the problem is that, I can get UITabBar Hidden for first UIViewController, but for second it is also hidden.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` method. Try your code for **hiding tabbar** in your `ViewController`, like

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

and for **showing tabbar**

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

The above one will work, but the problem is it'll leave an **empty space** in `viewController` bottom. To overcome this, set `frame` to your `tabbarController`.

For **Hiding**, set

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 50)]
```

For **Showing**, set

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)]
```

Comment: You know iPhone 5? Better use `self.view.frame.size.height` instead of 480.